# Converting Excel Formula to VBA and use Array

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert the following excel formula to VBA code:

```
=C10+H:H
```

UPDATE:
I want to take the values in column H of Worksheet1 and add them to the value in cell C10. I then want to compare that new value to a range of values in column C in Worksheet 2. I have been using the entire column because the rows that use the data in that column fluctuate.

I want to be able to look at the data a decade at a time. So at 10 years I am using Worksheet1!H20:H30. Then at 20 years I would use Worksheet1!H20:H40 and so on.

I could reasonably for VBA purposes limit the range from the entire column to Worksheet1!H20:H1000 (maybe even less, not sure just yet). The data in column H is what I need to put in an array and then need to be able to add to that data (will probably need to store result in second array) and then compare the result to an additional grouping of data on a separate worksheet (i.e. Worksheet2!C:C).

I need to calculate age based on annual incremental increases. I have my starting age stored in C10. I have the annual increments stored in column H. The way it works in excel is if I have this in cell B22 it add C10 to H22.

This formula is wrapped in a long and daunting if statement. It compares the calculated age to an age range on a different worksheet in lets say column C (i.e. Worksheet2!C:C = C10 + Worksheet1!H:H).

I need to be able to do that in VBA.

I tried in VBA
    ElseIf Worsheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C") = C10 + Worsheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")

It throw a match error.

UPDATE: FOR LOOP IN FUNCTION I TRIED TO USE

```
Function arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr_stnd_mbr() As Variant

    'SETS THE VARIABLES
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_Calculator_TL_30yrMaxTerm As Worksheet
    Dim ws_LVRates As Worksheet
    Dim ws_TLRates As Worksheet
    Dim ws_Misc As Worksheet
    Dim rngCalc_30yrMax_age_mbr As Range
    Dim rngCalc_30yrMax_age_sp As Range
    Dim rngCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr As Range
    Dim arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr As Variant
    Dim arrAge_Annual_Inc As Variant
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Column As Long

    'SETS RANGE FOR rngCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr RANGE
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_Calculator_TL_30yrMaxTerm = Worksheets("Calculator_TL_30yrMaxTerm")
    Set ws_LVRates = wb.Worksheets("LVRates")
    Set ws_TLRates = wb.Worksheets("TLRates")
    Set ws_Misc = wb.Worksheets("Misc")
    Set rngCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr = ws_Calculator_TL_30yrMaxTerm.Range("Calc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr")

    'SETS ARRAY EQUAL TO rngCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr
    arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr = rngCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr

    'LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF WORKSHEET VALUES
    For Row = 1 To UBound(arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr, 1) 'First array dimension is rows.
        For Column = 1 To UBound(arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr, 1) 'Secong array dimension is columns.
            arrAge_Annual_Inc = arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr + rngCalc_30yrMax_age_mbr
        Next Column
    Next Row



End Function
```

Comment: General question - how do you suppose you're going to add a single cell's value (`C10`) to an entire column reference `H:H`? Do you mean `C10 + sum(H:H)`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - The formula in excel automatically finds the row that is associated with the formula. The formula for example is located in B22, it would add C10 to H22. I need to do that in VBA.

Comment: General Question #2: C10 + H:H, means you want to add the value in C10 to every cell in column H?

Comment: @BruceWayne - That is correct. C10 hold current age. The values in column H hold how many year to add to the current age over a 30 year time period. So Year 1 we add age + 0, Year 2 we add age + 1, etc. and so on over said 30 year time frame. I am converting this to a macro so I can run years in 10 year increments. This needs to happen as I stated earlier in a complex if statement that compares age on one worksheet against age on another worksheet. I tried to just use Offset. But that didn't work.

Comment: @BruceWayne This is what I originally tried before I realized I need to use an array for column H:

For Each r In rngStandardRate_mbr
        If rngYr11 = "Year 11" Then
            ElseIf rngTLRates_age = r.Offset(0, 6).Value + rngCalc_30yrMax_age_mbr Then
            .
               End If
    Next r

Comment: "the formula in excel automatically finds the row" - what formula?

Comment: @QHarr  - The formula =C10 + H:H. If you have that in cell B22 it will add C10 with H22.

Comment: In that circumstance, the formula adds the contents of `C10` to every cell in column `H`.  However, it only **displays**, the result of the addition of `C10+H22`.  If you examine more closely, you would find a very large array of values in `B22`

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you clarify, in words, exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Then provide some examples of data input and desired output.  (Do this by editing your original question, not in the comments which are difficult to format).  I'm sure your name'd ranges are clear to you, but they are confusing for me to follow.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I made the edits you requested to my original request. I am almost certain I need to up these ranges (I.e  Worksheet2!C:C, Worsheet1!H:H, etc.) into arrays. The problem is I don't know how to then get the information out of the arrays. 

I can put the data into an array:

     arrCalc_30yrMax_age_annual_incr = ws_Calculator_TL_30yrMaxTerm.Range("H:H").Value

I need to know how to then get the data out of the array and add the original age to it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I also tried to put in a For Loop inside a function: fncCurrentAge_annual_incr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(r.Offset(0, 6).Value, rngCalc_30yrMax_age_mbr) and that didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not clear on what you want to do. I do not see any data input or desired output values in what you have added.  If you want to make the formula `=C10+H:H` into an array, you will have an array of `1,048,576` entries which will take forever to set up and calculate in VBA. I don't believe that is what you want to do, or perhaps you are not understanding exactly what `=C10+H:H` represents.

Comment: @ron: the H:H will be reduced to a single cell because Excel will apply implicit intersection in the formula (which is extremely efficient)

Comment: @ron: but VBA does not do Implicit Intersect - you need to make the VBA do it explicitly

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I will edit my original comment. Yes, I do understand exactly what =C10+H:H does!

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I agree with you. But I am having a problem understanding exactly what the poster wants, speaking about needing to turn the formula into an array, and getting information out of them.  If you treat the formula as an array, and apply the `SUM` function, the result will be  `C10*1048576 + SUM(H:H)` I doubt that is what he wants, but I can't figure it out.  And yes, I can relate C10 to the cell that is being calculated (implicit intersection), but I'm having a problem visualizing his data and figuring out how to advise him.

Comment: @KDGordon with regard to the formula in your edited post, you can't compare a single cell to a range in VBA like you can in Excel; you have to either loop through; or use `worksheetfunction.match` in an array; or use `range.find` on the worksheet.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - I did not know that Excel will apply implicit intersection in the formula and VBA can't. That explains why my VBA code that I tried to do that with didn't work.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I don't want to put the entire formula in an array. Just the H:H column. If that is too big (and I concede your point on that) I could condense that to a range such as H20:H1000. I did try a For Loop that I had in my original message, but took out to try to condense my request per your instructions. 

I just need to get the data in Worksheet1 in each row of column H and add that to the data in C10 and then compare the result for each row to the data in Worksheet2 in each row of column C.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I added the For Loop in it's entirety to the original message at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent data and desired results, I remain uncertain as to just what you want. Perhaps this approach will help, if my assumptions are correct. If not, I'll delete it.

I think what you are trying to do (based on your ELSEIF statement above)

- examine each value in Column C
- find the value in Column H that is equal to that value +10
- if you find such a value, do something.
- if your comparison is more complicated (eg finding an inexact match, and the values in column H are sorted, a different approach should be used)

Here is one way of doing it. (and there are a number of others, in addition to looping through all the data -- exactly which is best (fastest) depends on the circumstances.

```
Option Explicit

'Worsheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C") = C10 + Worsheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")

Sub Marine()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim vToFind 'declare as a type of value ?date  ?long ?double
    Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

'set ranges to end at the last used cell in the columns
With ws1
    Set r1 = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
End With
With ws2
    Set r2 = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each c1 In r1
    vToFind = c1 - Range("c10")
        Set c2 = r2.Find(what:=vToFind, after:=r2(1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c2 Is Nothing Then
            'do your thing
            Stop
        Else
            MsgBox vToFind & " not found in target"
        End If
Next c1

End Sub
```

Comment: will try that! I’m trying to calculate insurance rates based on age over a course of x years, 10 years at a time max 30 years.

Comment: Thank you that worked with a few modifications. CHEERS!